# AttributeError 'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv, pymysql

I'm trying to import some CSV files to a table on a MySQL database. The CSV files are updated daily and my intention is to use this program in python to automate the process.
The idea is: if the information already exists, I want to update it. If the information doesn't exist, I want to insert the data.

But I'm having this error:

**AttributeError
'DictCursor' object has no attribute 'update'**

Thanks in advance.

```
csv_data = csv.reader(open('ATEG_REGIONAL_MG_DADOS_TB_ATIVIDADE.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-15'), delimiter=';') 
next(csv_data)

for row in csv_data:
    for i, l in enumerate(row):
        if row[i] == '':
            row[i] = None
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM atividade WHERE CD_ATIVIDADE=%s', row[0])
        if cursor.fetchall():
            cursor.update('UPDATE atividade WHERE CD_ATIVIDADE = row[0]'),
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO atividade (CD_ATIVIDADE, NM_ATIVIDADE, ST_ATIVO, COD_USUARIO_INCLUSAO, COD_USUARIO_ALTERACAO, DAT_INCLUSAO, DAT_ALTERACAO, CO_ATIVIDADE_REZOLVE, ROWID, FLG_SAFRA, FLG_PRODUTIVO, FLG_TIPO_ATIVIDADE, FLG_INDICADOR_ISA) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)

# close the connection to the database. 
db.commit() 
cursor.close() 
print("Imported!")
```

Comment: Simply provide CSV to MySQL. Then load it to temptable (LOAD DATA) and merge into working table (REPLACE INTO or INSERT .. ODKU). This is more simple, more fast and less expensive procedure.

Comment: Thanks, I will try! @Akina

Answer (score 0):

If you are using psycopg2, there is no `cursor.update()` function present. Try `cursor.execute()` instead.

---

Also row[0] is considered as a string in your query. So, change it to:

`cursor.execute('UPDATE atividade WHERE CD_ATIVIDADE = ' + row[0])`

Comment: Thanks @Muhammed Jaseem
  I've tried to change to cursor.execute but now the error is: ProgrammingError
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE CD_ATIVIDADE = row[0]' at line 1")..

I'm very new on this..I can't see where is the SQL syntax error...

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: thanks for the update in your comment, but I'm having the same error:
`ProgrammingError
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE CD_ATIVIDADE = '1'' at line 1")'`

Comment: Check now (converted string to integer)

Comment: Now the error is:
TypeError
%d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: @Yasmim check now

Comment: Now the error: 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; came back..

Comment: @Yasmim yeah that's because you are not specifying what you want to update in your SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are confusing two different libraries.
`import MySQLdb` and `from flask_mysqldb import MySQL` are two different libraries.

Since you are using `flask` adding this line `app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'` and then calling the cursor `cursor=db.connection.cursor()` should solve your problem.

Taken from the [official git page](https://github.com/alexferl/flask-mysqldb)